# What does "for (int clickableId : clickableIds)" do?

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop

I'm newbie on android. I know only C and C++. I saw following `for` loop on [github](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/blob/master/BasicSamples/TypeANumber/src/main/java/com/google/example/games/tanc/MainMenuFragment.java#L77) reference.

```
for (int clickableId : clickableIds) {
            view.findViewById(clickableId).setOnClickListener(this);
        }
```

I googled about range based for loop for android because I know C++ and in C++ that syntax is range based for loop. But, I can't get any reference.

So,

- what does this for loop do?
- When and where should I use that?

Comment: See [The `for` Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html), the bottom half of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the whole code in github:

```
  final int[] clickableIds = new int[]{
            R.id.easy_mode_button,
            R.id.hard_mode_button,
            R.id.show_achievements_button,
            R.id.show_leaderboards_button,
            R.id.sign_in_button,
            R.id.sign_out_button
    };

    for (int clickableId : clickableIds) {
        view.findViewById(clickableId).setOnClickListener(this);
    }
```

It means `int clickableId` is iterating through the array `clickableIds`. So it entered the first one `R.id.easy_mode_button` then inside the for loop `onclicklistener` method will be invoked.

This for loop is called enhanced for loop this is the syntax for it:

`for (int myValue : myArray) {`

```
onClickListener(this) //this means current class is implementing onClickListener.
```

So after it enters the for loop, `onClickListener(this)` is called and when the button is clicked `onClick()` is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

It is a for-each loop. When you see the colon (:) read it as "in". You don't have to declare the iterator, so you don't have to provide a generic declaration for it (compiler does it for us). Like Peter Haddad said it means that `clickableId` will get all array `clickableIds`values one by one and set widgets (buttons here) clickable.

You should use the for-each loop anytime you can, it really beautifies your code. But you cannot use it everytime, for example if the program needs acces to the iterator in order to remove the current element...